# Pixel Qi screen operation

Tags: display, backlight

I just installed Pixel Qi screen (PQ101WX01) on my Acer Aspire One D270, but I can only control dimming of the screen through OS. 
Dimming doesn't make it more readable in the sunlight, and going to sleep turns the screen completely black.

How do I shut down backlight and switch Pixel Qi screen mode of operation to readable in the sun?

I have access to both Windows 7 and Ubuntu (13 or more newer).

Comment: What you have said is basically what it does. The backlight is a backlight,it just becomes less effective when there is so much light hitting the front. Sleep closes the panels light valves off altogether . It is transreflective en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transflective_liquid_crystal_display basically it just has high level of reflection behind the pannel bouncing light back through the lcd light valves. I do not understand what else you want to happen? I do not think that there is any "switching" of the reflection, what you see is what you get.

Comment: But, here's the quote from Clover's SunBook having PixelQi display: "In daylight, the backlight can be turned off completely, cutting the power consumption, extending battery life, and reducing eyestrain.  Reflective mode provides 1024 x 600 resolution in black & white."
This is the feature I am searching for.

Comment: ahh like an e-ink mode. A dual display, they have not yet put that on the normal market yet? (that I know of, and it would not be an easy thing to combine the 2) . The model number you used, does not seem to be of that type either?  Do you have a link to the page with the quote on it? Is it from this same location that you purchaced this item?

Comment: True, I bought it of reseller in Taiwan on ebay.
Quote I used is from this source [link](http://cloversystems.com/products/other/sunbook)
And I can read on Pixel Qi website [link](http://www.pixelqi.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/docs/PQ101WX01_20121029V10.306201705.pdf) for the This module
also supports two low power modes: a transflective mode and a reflective mode with lower color.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and help. After talking to the Pixel Qi company, it seams like the screen I got was a fake one, so be careful when ordering off ebay.

Answer (score -2):

try linux and see if the screen is still readable after turning of backlight ( with sun behind the screen) .
I bought that pixelqi screen and ubuntu allow to set the backlight to any level (after a few tweaks google will help).